# User profile won't display for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm have some issues with devise. I've added a users table (devise), an appointments table and a profiles table to my app. One user should have many appointments, and have one profile.

The problem is that I can't display the profile for that user. It tells me that there is No route matches [GET] "/profile/1"

I wonder if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong, and why?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
resources :profiles
resources :appointments

root 'page#home'
get 'page/testimonials'
get '/signedinuserprofile' => 'profiles#signedinuserprofile'
#get 'page/home'
```

profiles controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @profiles = Profile.all
end

def signedinuserprofile
  profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    if profile.nil?
      redirect_to "/profile/new"
    else
      @profile = Profile.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
      redirect_to "/profile/#{@profile.id}"
    end
end
```

application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  "/signedinuserprofile"
end
end
```

sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 #after_sign_in_path_for is called by devise
 def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    "/signedinuserprofile" # here I provide the path for the user's profile
end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use a resourceful route yet you don't have a show action in your controller. Add a show action and find the user from the params @profile.id

You are essentially redirecting to an action that you don't have in your profiles controller.

Comment: Thank you very much